# Autoregressive Recursive Filtering in Statsmodels - 0.5.0 v. 0.6.0

Tags: python, time-series, anaconda, statsmodels

Version 0.5.0 of Statsmodels does not contain an obvious function to run an autoregressive recursive filter on time series data. There is an existing function for autoregressive filtering

```
statsmodels.tsa.filters.arfilter()
```

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/notebooks/generated/statsmodels.tsa.filters.arfilter.html

And version 0.6.0's new function:

```
statsmodels.tsa.filters.filtertools.recursive_filter()
```

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.filters.filtertools.recursive_filter.html

However, there does not appear to be an easy way to perform this for me right now as I'm on Anaconda (current SM version: 0.5.0). How is anyone else achieving this type of filtering?

Comment: `scipy.signal.lfilter` is an ARMA filter. Several of these functions in statsmodels are just wrappers around fast scipy.signal functions, with some translation from signal processing to time series analysis (same thing, but different terminology and applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use `conda update`?

The source for recursive_filter is here.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/filters/filtertools.html#recursive_filter

As mentioned, it's just lfilter with proper handling of initial conditions.

Comment: For whatever reason, 'update' wasn't letting me update statsmodels beyond the built in 0.5.0 version. I tried conda install statsmodels=0.6.1 this morning and .recursive_filter() is now present due to the version change.